# How can I stretch content background image to full screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML. With the following:

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="bg_img"></div>
  <h1>morning</h1>
  <h2>today</h2>
  <p>lorem ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

Background image to this content CSS:

```
#container .item .bg_img{background:url('../img/mainpage/demo.jpg') no-repeat;}
```

This structure is working ok. But I want to attach this background images to body and full screen size. How can I do this via JavaScript or pure jQuery (no plugin)?

Comment: can you create a fiddle and link it here?

Comment: [You can do it with pure CSS](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/). There is a jQuery version on that page too.

Comment: try to use `background-size: cover;`

Answer (score 1):

Try below code...

```
 #container .item .bg_img{
   background: url('/img/mainpage/demo.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
 }
```

Comment: background-size:cover only full screen in this item class. But I want all screen is full image.

Comment: set width and height of #container to 100% and it worked like charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS:

```
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: background-size:cover only full screen in this item class. But I want all screen is full image

Comment: @DokuzTaneOn try background-size: 100% 100%;

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean an image that is related to the context of the body and not of .item?

You can use position:fixed for that. A top, left, bottom and right will ensure it will take the whole page.

background-size: cover will make sure the image itself will cover the page. Depending on the image you use, you might want another solution. Ex: you can center an image and fade to a background color (but that's up to you)

Use a z-Index of -1 to ensure it does not obscure your content

```
item .bg_img {
    background:url('http://www.ninahale.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Post-Enhanced-Campaigns-World.jpg') fixed center center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Aa8fe/

Answer (score -1):

Even i struggled for the same and atlast i got a solution..its below..

```
    body //your container name
    {
        background-image: url(Images/caramel%20gradient%20for%20website.png);
        background-size: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: background-size:cover only full screen in this item class. But I want all screen is full image

Comment: I din get you..U mean u have single image which must be stretched to the window size.